# Unable to upload file using php on the server, getting error 7

Tags: php, apache, server

I am getting the error 7 while uploading the file on the server. I have also increased the max_upload_filesize value but of no use. I am getting the values in $_FILES as :

```
Array
(
    [name] => Screenshot (1).png
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 7
    [size] => 0
)
```

I am using Digital Ocean Server. If anybody knows the solution please help me out.

Comment: Make sure disk is not full. If you don't routinely trim error logs you can run out of disk space.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: my disk was full but now I have cleared the some data now I have enough space